# Solutions to this non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

any clue for the equation $y' = \lfloor{y}\rfloor$ ? Thanks !
I've tried basic tricks but none worked out.

Comment: Do you allow non-differentiable functions as solutions of this ODE? Because there's a clear issue in the fact that a derivative must satisfy the intermediate value property.

Comment: Edit : sorry, my English is bad and I didn't understand your question properly. How could non-differentiable functions work in this specific case ? I'm new to the topic so sorry if it's something well-known.

Comment: I don't know, but it is quite clear that if the discussion is restricted to differentiable functions, then there are points at which no solution is defined. Is that ok?

Comment: Ok ok thank you I see. So non-differentiable functions would be more appropriated right ? Being a freshman, I don't think that those are awaited but I'm curious about it.

Comment: Mathematics isn't about "tricks", it's about definitions and theorems. Due to the intermediate value theorem, a derivative can't have jumps, so $y' = \lfloor{y}\rfloor$ is possible only as long as $y$ stays between two integers.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are constant solutions $y = c$ for $0 \le c < 1$, and solutions $y = at + b$ where $a$ is a nonzero integer, defined for $a < at + b < a+1$.
You can't go past $at+b = a$ or $a+1$ unless you allow [weak solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've looked at the link and it cleared some misunderstandings for me ! What would make someone allow weak solutions or not ? Is it purely arbitrary ? I'm new to differential equations, sorry if the questions are too basic.

Comment: Basically it might depend on the application.  In this case I don't think there is an application, you just arbitrarily wrote down the differential equation, so you get to choose what kind of solutions you want to allow.